# PyCharm: How can I make pycharm support mouse horizontal scroll

Tags: pycharm

My mouse support horizontal scroll .It works well in visual studio ,and other editor. But i didn't worked on PyCharm or or JetBrain's product .Do any one know how to setting PyCharm .And make it support mouse horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can.

According to the [mouse reference doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/mouse-reference.html) they already mapped **<kbd>Shift</kbd> + mouse scroll** (the regular one, I guess) to horizontal scroll action.

And in terms of [configurable mouse shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/enter-mouse-shortcut-dialog.html) for actions - I only see clickable buttons being configurable.